# ¿Como realizar operaciones dentro de un archivo y escribir el resultado a otro archivo de salida?

Tags: java

Buen dia, estoy teniendo unos problemas en un ejercicio de Java que tuve en mi clase. Lo que necesito hacer es en un archivo de entrada .txt poner cualquier contenido ya sea palabras o numeros pero al momento de tener una operacion, el resultado se debe mostrar en un archivo .txt de salida junto con el texto que haya escrito.

Por el momento pude realizar que el contenido del archivo de entrada se reflejara en el de salida, pero tengo problemas en la parte de las operaciones.

Tengo este codigo donde intente realizar las operaciones pero me marca un error al ingresar los nombres, es este:

C:\Users\PC\Desktop>java miCalc enter.txt salida.txt
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at miCalc.(miCalc.java:35)
        at miCalc.main(miCalc.java:11)

```
import java.io.*;
public class miCalc{
    String input, output;
    char operacion;
    String[] num;
    float resultado;
    String dataFiles;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = args[0];
        String output = args[1];
        miCalc fileOp = new miCalc(input,output);
    }
    public miCalc(String input, String output){
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
        try{
            File f1 = new File(input);
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f1);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            do{
                dataFiles=br.readLine();
                if(dataFiles!=null){
                    for(int i=0;i<dataFiles.length();i++){
                        if(dataFiles.charAt(i)=='+' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='-' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='*' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='/'){
                            operacion=dataFiles.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                    String c=operacion+"";
                    num=dataFiles.split("\\"+c);
                    if(operacion=='+'){
                         resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])+Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                        bw.write(resultado+"");
                        bw.newLine();
                    }

                    else if(operacion=='-'){
                        resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])-Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                        bw.write(resultado+"");
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                    else if(operacion=='*'){
                        resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])*Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                        bw.write(resultado+"");
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                    else if(operacion=='/'){
                        resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])/Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                        bw.write(resultado+"");
                        bw.newLine();
                    }

                }
            }while(dataFiles!=null);
                br.close();
                bw.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
        catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que pudiera estar causando el error?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías añadir el contenido del fichero de entrada enter.txt?

Comment: Si, lo que debe incluir dentro del archivo es `hola 5.0 + 5.0 mundo 3.0 * 3.0`  Y lo que deseo realizar es que en el archivo de salida aparezcan las operaciones ya realizadas junto con los mensajes es decir `hola 10.0 mundo 9.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que limpiar la variable `operacion`, puedes definir después de la declaración de `do`. Actualmente se queda almacenada con el valor obtenido de la última operación y por eso causa error cuando lee la siguiente linea.

Ejemplo:

```
...
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
do {
    operacion = '\0'; //-------------------> Aquí limpias la variable
    dataFiles = br.readLine();
    if (dataFiles != null) {
....
```

Es necesario evaluar que la linea leida no tenga números y letras porque se produciría un error de ejecución, eso se puede corregir utilizando expresiones regulares, aquí el ejemplo completo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class miCalc {
    String input, output;
    char operacion;
    String[] num;
    float resultado;
    String dataFiles;
    String REGEX = "^[0-9\\-\\+\\*\\/\\.]*"; // --------------------------------------------> valida que haya numeros los signos de operación y caracter decimal

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = args[0];
        String output = args[1];
        miCalc fileOp = new miCalc(input, output);
    }

    public miCalc(String input, String output) {
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
        try {
            File f1 = new File(input);
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f1);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            do {
                operacion = '\0';
                dataFiles = br.readLine();
                if (dataFiles != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataFiles.length(); i++) {
                        if (dataFiles.charAt(i) == '+' || dataFiles.charAt(i) == '-' || dataFiles.charAt(i) == '*' || dataFiles.charAt(i) == '/') {
                            operacion = dataFiles.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                    String c = operacion + "";
                    Pattern.compile(REGEX); // ---------------------------------------------> Compila la expresión regular

                    if (dataFiles.matches(REGEX) && operacion != '\0') { // ----------------> Evalua que se cumpla con la expresión regular
                        num = dataFiles.split("\\" + c);
                        if (operacion == '+') {
                            resultado = Float.parseFloat(num[0]) + Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                            bw.write(resultado + "");
                            bw.newLine();
                        } else if (operacion == '-') {
                            resultado = Float.parseFloat(num[0]) - Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                            bw.write(resultado + "");
                            bw.newLine();
                        } else if (operacion == '*') {
                            resultado = Float.parseFloat(num[0]) * Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                            bw.write(resultado + "");
                            bw.newLine();
                        } else if (operacion == '/') {
                            resultado = Float.parseFloat(num[0]) / Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                            bw.write(resultado + "");
                            bw.newLine();
                        }
                    } else {
                        bw.write(dataFiles);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
            } while (dataFiles != null);
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo intentare en el codigo, solo que me queda duda en como realizar en si las operaciones si es que lee algun numero. Un compañero de clases me comento el usar el charAt con un ciclo for que pase por todo el contenido.

Comment: 1. En la línea del `if (dataFiles.charAt(i)...` estas evaluado que la linea leida del archivo contenga alguno de los caracteres de operación `(+, -, *, / )`.
2. En la linea `num = dataFiles.split("\\" + c);` estas separando en un array los valores que separan la operación, es decir, si lee `5+3` en va a guardar `num[0]=5` y en `num[1]=3`
3. En cada if evalua el valor de la variable `operacion`, dependiendo de ese valor realizará la operación.
_Ten en cuenta que solo está evaluando dos digitos_